# Applying again for PhD abroad vs. staying at my home institution?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm a MS student who recently (unsuccessfully) applied to PhD programs in the US (I'm from an Asian country but was raised there). I'm in a situation where I have the option to apply again this round, or to just stay at my home institution where I received my bachelor's and will receive my master's.

Pros of applying again would be that I wouldn't have any "regrets" and in the hypothetical situation that I'm successful I'd be able to be open to more (hypothetical) experiences/networks/opportunities. Pros of staying would be that my current lab pays well, my friends and family are here, the quality of research isn't too terrible (my lab isn't one of those labs that produces 10+ publications a year, but we still do a decent job), my and my PI's overall a nice person. Not to mention that I'd *probably* be able to finish my degree faster and either go for a postdoc or internship/job abroad. The PhD at my home institution is pretty much a guarantee to get in, since my advisor is very keen on my staying and the school's admissions process if extremely faculty-based.

I suppose the main factor that's holding me back from applying again is the feeling that it'd be a gamble. The only things I can do to improve my application would be to get a good quality publication out and raise the quality of my letters. My undergrad GPA is bad (barely above 3.0/4.0) but there's nothing I can do about that. I'm not sure if I'd be able to get better quality letters in that time, as in my home country working with other professors/labs is usually frowned upon. Even this round I had to ask a postdoc for one of my letters.

I'm also concerned, albeit to a lesser degree, about this concept of "academic incest" where you attend the same school for your undergrad and PhD. I don't think this would be that big of an issue, but I guess I wouldn't really know better.

I guess the point of this question/post would be to seek some advice on how more seasoned people would view my situation and what they would do. Please flag if inappropriate. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to live and work after you finish your education?

Comment: @Buffy Preferably the US or Canada. It's been 15 years since I've went back and I kind of want to go home. I've heard that if that's the case then it may be better to apply again - even if it means going to a "lower ranked" school.